# Why is dynamic_cast to a non-unique base class type allowed?

Tags: c++

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast:

`dynamic_cast < new_type > ( expression )`

> 3) If `new_type` is a pointer or reference to Base, and the type of `expression` is a pointer or reference to Derived, where Base is a **unique**, accessible base class of Derived, the result is a pointer or reference to the Base class subobject within the Derived object pointed or identified by `expression`. (Note: an implicit conversion and `static_cast` can perform this conversion as well.)

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
//public:
//  virtual ~A() {
//
//  }
};

class B : public A {

};

class C : public B {

};

class D : public B, public A {

};

int main()
{
    D* pd = new D;
    if (B* pa = dynamic_cast<B*>(pd)) {
        cout << "1";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No error or warning under VC++

`warning: direct base 'A' inaccessible in 'D' due to ambiguity` under gcc, [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VE1cooGKgB1VBhaK)

Shouldn't I expect a compile error?

---

Now I find that if I try to convert `D*` to `A*`, a error would occur, but as mentioned above, from `D*` to `B*`, no error.

```
int main()
{
    D* pd = new D;
    if (A* pa = dynamic_cast<A*>(pd)) {
        cout << "1";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fCYhv7xkSLITIhWQ)

Comment: Could you amend this please, you don't have a polymorphic structure here.

Comment: @Bathsheba But this casting rule 3) doesn't mention polymorphic type, I aim to make it non-polymorphic here to do some experiments.

Comment: Hum. This is clearly above my paygrade. Let's wait for some experts to wade in. Upvote for good feelings.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you :D. I am merely being curious.

Comment: Is not `B` in Your example unique base class of `D`? No wonder it compiles

Comment: @bartop Hum... That seems to make sense. I thought *unique* means "1 and only base class".

Comment: vc++ 2017 15.8 issues `warning C4584: 'D': base-class 'A' is already a base-class of 'B'`

Comment: @VTT That warning occurs whenever you have duplicated base class with multiple inheritance. It's not related to dynamic_cast.. I have that too.

Comment: @bartop I think your understanding of *unqiue* is correct.

Comment: In your first case, there is no ambiguity of `B` within `D`, so there is no reason to expect an error from `dynamic_cast<B*>(pd)`.   VC++ is being kind to you, by warning that `A` is an ambiguous base of `D`, but since there is no attempt to convert a `D *` to an `A*`, there is no diagnosable error.   In the second case, `dynamic_cast<A*>(pd)`, there is a diagnosable error, since the conversion is ambiguous.     In short:   both compilers are correct, but VC++ gives an additional warning.   Compilers are not required to give warnings.

Comment: You have the single inheritance, you don't have to extend `D` from `A` and `B` together since `B` is already extending `A` so you can cast any `B` as well as any class publicly extending `B` like 'C' or  'D' to `A`. Nevertheless, if 'D' must extend `C` and `B` then it must be `class D: public virtual A, public B, public C` to avoid "diamond inheritance".

Comment: @Peter, GCC gives the warning, not VC++. Otherwise, I agree, and you should make that an answer.

Comment: @Rick, the cppreference wording could be improved slightly, but " where Base is a unique, accessible base class of Derived" does not mean "where Derived only has one base class, which is of type Base". It means "there is exactly one base class of type Base among Derived's (possibly multiple) base classes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context, **unique** means that Derived *contains* `new_type` only once, not that Derived derives from a single base class.

So, in your example, `B` is unique, because `D` *contains* it only once.

In your example, `D` *contains* `A` twice (once directly, and once through `B`), so a cast to `A` cannot be made, as `A` is not unique.

Note, that "containment" what it counts. So, in this example, `C` derives from `Base` twice, yet it is fine, as `Base` is inherited with the keyword `virtual`:

```
struct Base { };
struct A: virtual Base { };
struct B: virtual Base { };
struct C: A, B { };

int main() {
    C c;
    dynamic_cast<Base &>(c);
}
```

(If I haven't used `virtual`, then `Base` would have been ambiguous)

Note: I'd use `static_cast` instead, as it can do the cast in this case as well. Using `dynamic_cast` is a little bit misleading here, as the cast will be done compile-time, and not run-time.

Comment: Yes, he used `dynamic_cast` while there wasn't anything dynamic :)

Answer (score 0):

The warning causes by indirect base class issue in multiple-inheritance model. `D` has two copies of base class `A`, one directly and one indirectly via `B`. When a base class is specified as a virtual base (same as @geza example), there is only one copy of base class' data members shared between virtual base classes.

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() {}
};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
    B() : A() {}
};

class C : public B, virtual public A {
public:
    C() : B() {}
};

int main()
{
  A* pa = static_cast<A *>(new C()); // no more warning since A is virtual
  return 0;
}
```

It's well explained here: [Multiple Base Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/multiple-base-classes?view=vs-2017).